# $\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{4z^2}{(z-1)^2} = 4$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, infinity

So, I'm having trouble performing the $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ for this proof.

I made the change from $z$ to $\frac{1}{z}$ so the limit becomes $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{4}{(1-z)^2} = 4$.

Next, I applied the definition for the limit: $ \left|  \frac{4}{(1-z)^2} - 4  \right| < \varepsilon$ when $\left| z \right| < \delta$. Then, after performing some math I get to $ \left|  \frac{-z^2 +2z}{(1-z)^2}\right| < \frac{|z||z-2|}{|z-1|} < \varepsilon $.

Finally I choose $\delta<5$ that makes $ z-2 < 3$ and $ z-1 < 4$ and $ \delta $ is min{$5, \frac{4 \varepsilon}{3} $}.

I don't know if that is right or if there is a better way to do it.

Edit: This problem is from "Complex variables and applications" Brown & Churchill

Comment: You forgot the square on the second expression before epsilon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the step of setting an upper bound on $\delta$ it needs to be chosen so that  $\left| \frac {z-2}{z-1}\right|$ is bounded.

$\delta \le 4$ will not do the trick!  We can't let the denominator equal zero.

Choose $\delta \le \frac 12$ (we could choose any value less than 1, but this is easy to work with)

In wich case $\left |\frac {z-2}{z-1}\right|< 5$

$\delta = \min (\frac \epsilon 5, \frac 12)$

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

But there a few things I didn't understand yet:

You said that $ \delta \le 4$ won't do the trick an then you choose $ \delta \le \frac{1}{2}$ even when $ \frac{1}{2} < 4$. Is that a mistake?

The second thing, just to make sure I got it right, when I'm doing $ \left| z -z_{0} \right| $ I'm drawing a circle surrounding $z_{0}$ but, when I do $ \left| \frac{1}{z- z_{0}} \right| $ I have to avoid a circle that includes $ z_{0}$ because that'll go to $ \infty $. Did I got it right?

Comment: $4$ is too big to constrain $\delta.$  If we say "Let $\delta \le 4$ and for all $z$ such that $|z|\le \delta$ then it is possible that $z = 1$ in which case $|\frac {z-2}{z-1}|$ is undefined.  Or $z$ is very nearly $1$ in which case $|\frac {z-2}{z-1}|$ is unbounded.